# how to avoid to get stuck while opening a process that wait

Tags: python, shell

I am having a little problem: I am basically trying to open a connection via tcprelay, but when I run it in a shell script; the window show that the process starts forwarding, but the cursor stay there, blinking.

```
python tcprelay.py -t 22:2222
Forwarding local port 2222 to remote port 22
```

Whatever I add after the call to this process, never gets executed.

I wonder, how can you launch process like tcprelay, and at the same time leave it there open, while you maybe create a connection via SSH or telnet?

I've tried to put the process in background, with the &, but the result is the same.

I am trying to connect to this device via telnet or ssh, execute some commands and then close the connection, but I am stuck here.

If I run manually the whole thing, I just open a shell window, running tcprelay, then I open a different window and do my work there, but I have no idea how you can "script" this; so far was not successful in finding a solution.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Locking then run with `&` sounds strange. Are you sure it's not just echoing, overwriting the prompt, and exiting? Does pressing return give your prompt back?

Comment: No, it won't do anything until I use control-z; it just print out that is forwarding the traffic on remote port 22 of the remote host. Tried with and without the &, to put the process in background but it won't do any good sadly.

Answer (score 0):

What about nohup?

```
nohup python tcprelay.py -t 22:2222 &
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! Now the script continue after opening the tcprelay process.